# When i execute python program from raspberry pi terminal it shows me this error: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file

Tags: python, encoding, raspberry-pi, raspbian

please i have a problem with executing python files from raspbian terminal. So i made a gui first in windows and everything was working fine, so i decided to run it in my raspberry pi, when i execute the script from the python IDE of the rpi the program run without errors, but when i run it from the terminal it shows me  error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from test1.py import *
  File "/media/.../test1.py", line 8
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /media/.../test1.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I've looked in the internet for a solution and all solutions say to add those two lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But when i add them a new error appear which say:

```
No module named tkinter
```

Knowing that the first line of code after those two lines i added is

`import tkinter`

Can you help me guys solve this problem?

Comment: Either you don't have Tkinter installed, or you're running this with Python 2.x in which case the module name is capitalized.

Comment: No tkinter is intalled because when i run the program from python ide it works fine but when run it with a command line in terminal it shows me the error

Comment: Show us the code of `test1.py` around line 8! And BTW no `.py` in imports!

Comment: Running your program from IDE is not necessarily using the same Python version as running it from the terminal.  (Use `import sys; print(sys.version)` to check.)